# Android Studio Debug Filtering

Tags: android

I am having difficulties working with the Android Studio Debugger since it is logging everything the phone does and thus making code errors/exceptions locating very very difficult.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to filter these logs to only obtain the errors related to the app that I am currently debugging on my USB device?

I tried changing log level from Verbose to Debug then to Error but it still is complicated.

Your help is very appreciated, I need some guide to use it since I'm kind of newbie to such IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter which logs logcat should display. As seen in the image below, you can select the app you are running (1), and the option that only logs created by this app should be shown (2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio, at the extreme right of your logcat there should be a dropdown box, select `Edit Filter Configuration` from it then in the popup enter your package name in the `Package Name:` row.

That will filter the logcat messages to show only those from your app.